# Redirect URLs with page version to URL without version except css and js

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some links on my website with page version and I want visitors redirected to the same page but without version number.

I got help before by {arkascha} with this code in `.htaccess` to affect all links, but i couldn't modify it to make exception for css and js files because visitors cannot load new version of css and js on my site because the code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=\d+$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

example pages with version

```
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=1
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=2
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=3
```

example page after the code applied through htaccess

```
example.com/folder/locatedpage
```

I want the same code above but with exception for css and js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
> ```

Change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to exclude `.css` and `.js` files. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule !\.(css|js)$ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix negates the regex, so it is successful when it does not match. (Whereas `^` effectively matches everything.)

However, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the 301 (permanent) redirect (that erroneously applied to `.css` and `.js` files) will have been cached persistently by the browser (and possibly intermediary caches). Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: that is so great, i understand now how htaccess work, thank you so much.